# Recreating svn tags in git retrospectively

Tags: git, svn

I converted a Subversion repository to git a couple of weeks ago, thought that everything looked fine, then switched over to working with git exclusively. However, now I notice that I made a mistake when converting tags and branches.

The SVN repo had a hierarchy of tags. So, for instance, we had something like:

```
 branches
  project1
   1.0
   1.1
  project2
   1.0.0.1
```

etc. I now have git 'tags' project1 and project2. I tried to create the nested tags by running `git ls-tree project1`, then `git tag project1-1.0 <hash>`, but if I try to check the resulting tag out I get the message "Cannot switch branch to a non-commit". I see that I have tagged a tree rather than a commit.

Is there a clever way for me to create the tags manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @stuart for putting me on the right track. The process I used was a bit long-winded but I think I have the right results.

First I created a file containing svn links to my tag 'parent' folders (those containing the version-numbered tags.) I processed that file to create another one containing the paths contained in each of those parents:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

f = open('parents')
parentPaths = [x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines()]
f.close()

for parentPath in parentPaths:
  escapedPath = parentPath.replace('\\','\\\\').replace('/', '\\/').replace('&', '\\&')
  c = "svn ls '" + parentPath + "' | sed -e 's/\\(.*\\)/" + escapedPath + "\\/\\1/' >> paths"
  os.system(c)
```

Next I got SVN revision numbers for each of those paths using this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

f = open('paths')
ps = [ x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines() ]
f.close()

for p in ps:
  branchName = p.replace("svn://myrepo/tags/", "").strip(" ").rstrip("/\n").replace("/", "-").replace(" ", "-").replace(")", "").replace("(", "").lower()
  eBN = branchName.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("/", "\\/").replace("&", "\\&")
  c = "svn log '" + p + "' --stop-on-copy -l 1 -v | grep -E '\\(from .*:[0-9]+\\)$' | sed -e 's/.*(from .*:\\([0-9]*\\))$/\\1/' >> revs/" + eBN
  os.system(c)
```

One tag may contain several SVN log revision entries, so I munged the output of the above into a single file called revs.out:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

o = open('revs.out', 'w')
for filename in os.listdir('revs') :
 f = open('revs/' + filename)
 l = [ x.strip('\n') for x in f.readlines() ]
 f.close()
 o.write( "{0} {1}\n".format( max(l), filename ) )

o.close()
```

This contains, for instance:

```
4073 myproject-version-1.12.44
6982 myproject-version-1.13.9
```

The next bit gets a bit tricky. Most of the tags were made on trunk, and I got git commit refs for those like this (running in a git repo):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

f = open('../svn/revs.out')
revs = [ x.strip('\n').split(' ') for x in f.readlines() ]
f.close()

for rev in revs:
  r = rev[0]
  n = rev[1]

  c = "git log --all --grep 'trunk@" + r + " ' --pretty=format:%H | sed -e 's/\\(.*\\)/git tag " + n + " \\1\\n/' >> ~/src/svn/genTags.sh"
  os.system(c)
```

Other tags were made from branches, or from folders in the trunk hierarchy, or were otherwise empty tags created when a new folder was created in the 'tags' hierarchy. These cases I dealt with pretty much manually.

The result at this point was a script which would itself create git tags. Here is an excerpt:

```
git tag project1-1.2.0.2 86e0f47f37ee28a3b16be26e4ab81a39a24015aa
git tag project2-1.1.0.2 9cefabc1e8e66e974bb3d987a1089027535c8562
git tag project2-1.1.0.8 1d3e9abe6f4ec440806d32ed60ae80a2568778eb
```

I then ran the script to create the tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in `gitk` (turning on the all branches view), and find the `project1` branch, you will be able to see all of the commits on that branch. Go through and find the one which should be tagged, and then use `git tag <hash>`. Repeat for the other tags :)

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction. With about 450 tags to generate I had to come up with a scripted solution, and I have added an answer with details.